# nhibernate export hibernate.cfg.xml when configured by code

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, export

How can I export the hibernate.cfg.xml from the nhibernate configuration. I have configured nhibernate in code instead of importing the cfg.xml. I now have a need to export the cfg and the mapping xml files for import into other nhibernate tools. I found a way to export the mapping.xml but fail to find a method to export the cfg.

NHibernate 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an easy way how to do it. NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration does not contains any reference to NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration class which conforms to nhibernate-configuration-2.2 xml schema. You could try to infer all properties of HibernateConfiguration class from Configuration instance by your own.

NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration itself is serializable but it is serialized into quite different schema.

IMO fallback to traditional cfg.xml file would be far easier solution.